# Javascript Escape (\x) + Variable,

Tags: javascript

Been playing with Javascript and discover the escaped(\x) which seems interesting.

To clarify I just discover I can convert two digit number into a letter using escape + x,

like `"\x51"` output is `Q`

Been searching about this specific topic but not really sure where to start as I don't even know what they call it, like I know backslash purpose in PHP and Javascript but I don't know what it does when it combines with `x`

Now my question is, is it possible to add a dynamic number value after the X?

Like I'm trying to create a function like this but It doesn't seem possible, as it looks like it requires to have two characters (number or letter) after `x`.

```
function __num_string( num ) {
    return "\x"+num;
}
```

**expectation** `__num_string( 51 )` would return `Q`

**reality** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I would appreciate any clarification if its possible or not,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but there's a [better way to do it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

```
return String.fromCharCode(num);
```

... where `num` is a Unicode value of a character you want to get.

Still, technically it's possible to implement your function the way you originally intended, using `eval`:

```
function __num_string( num ) {
   if (/^[a-f0-9]{1,2}$/i.test(num)) { 
     return eval('"\\x' + num + '"');
   }
}
```

Note the difference: `num` should be a string representing a hexadecimal value.

---

Now about the error you got: this...

```
'\x'
```

... is technically invalid string. When parsing string literal, the parser expects the sequence `\x` to be followed by `[0-9a-f]` character range. Yet in your case there's nothing similar there, hence `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, really appreciate it,

Comment: @riana77ow just a follow-up, it doesn't look like ```String.fromCharCode()``` convert it the way i want it, ```String.fromCharCode(51)``` returns ```3``` whereas  ```"\x51"``` returns ```Q```

Comment: @SymmetricsWeb This is an absolute beginner error: Obviously 51 is not the same as 0x51. The first is decimal and the second is hexadecimal!

Answer (score 1):

String escaping is a syntactic feature, part of string literals.
It doesn't make sense to do that at runtime.

You're looking for `String.fromCharCode`, which does exactly what it sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

#### ***tldr***

- Pass 51₁₆ to `String.fromCharCode` not 51₁₀
- 51₁₆ is equal to 81₁₀
- Any of the following can be used for conversion
  - `(81).toString(16)`
  - `81..toString(16)`
  - `81.0.toString(16)`
  - `numberVar.toString(16)`

After reading the answers and comments in this question an investigation ensued.

Bearing in mind a hypothesis I'd formed from the question

Why do the main solutions, namely `String.fromCharCode`,
seem not to answer the asker's question when tried.

The hypothesis was that the issue lay within the type of argument passed to `String.fromCharCode`.

The following demonstrates in a node repl the reason why `'\x51' === 'Q'` returns `true` yet `String.fromCharCode(51) === 3` also returns `true`.

```
> 0x51 // es6 hexadecimal literal
81

> 0x51.toString(16) // Same as (81).toString(16)
'51'

> String.fromCharCode(0x51) // Same as String.fromCharCode(81)
'Q'

> (81).toString(16) // Same as 0x51.toString(16)
51

> String.fromCharCode(81) // Same as String.fromCharCode(0x51)
'Q'

> 0x33 // es6 hexadecimal literal
51

> 0x33.toString(16) // literal to base 16 string
'33'

> String.fromCharCode(0x33)
'3'

> String.fromCharCode(51)
'3'
```

Just the statements if you wanna try them yourself.

```
0x51
0x51.toString(16)
String.fromCharCode(0x51)
(81).toString(16)
String.fromCharCode(81)
0x33
0x33.toString(16)
String.fromCharCode(0x33)
String.fromCharCode(51)
```

It seems as if the method in question takes a hexadecimal string.

If it's a number it's toString() with 16 passed as base is called implicitly.

Below is a function which does the conversion.

```
function toHex(n) {
  if (typeof n === 'string') return `${parseInt(n, 16)}`;
  return `0x${n}`;
}
```

It can be used with a number

```
> String.fromCharCode(toHex(33))
'3'


> String.fromCharCode(toHex(51))
'Q'
```

It can be used with a string

```
> String.fromCharCode(toHex('33'))
'3'


> String.fromCharCode(toHex('51'))
'Q'
```

It can be used with hex digits but only as a string...

```
> String.fromCharCode(toHex('3f'))
'?'
```

because hex numeric literals are fine without it.

```
> String.fromCharCode(0x3f)
'?'
```